# HTML file with a footer that displays every printed page

Tags: html, css, printing, footer

I am trying to make a footer for a HTML file where the footer needs to display on every printed page. I found a topic with a solution that locks a specific text to every page I print.

HTML:

```
<div class="divFooter">This is a footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen {
  div.divFooter {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media print {
  div.divFooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the rest of my code just overwrites this whenever it reaches the footer. Anyone know a nice and quick solution for this? If not, maybe a different way to lock a footer to every page I print of that HTML file? I would also like to note that I cant link a seperate CSS file to the HTML. So every code I make, needs to be in the same file.

Comment: Look into the @page rule. I have never messed with it, but it looks like it might be what you're looking for. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the solution is not just to use HTML and CSS, but to use PHP, making a footer include on each page, so you have a fixed footer for each.

```
<html>
...
<? php

include_once ("footer.html");
?>
...
```